# how do you find the sizeof address and data bus

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

Recently I saw that this is a question which is asked in an interview.

how do you find the sizeof address and databus in a system.

You can find the sizeof address using sizeof for a pointer.

But how do we find the sizeof a data bus? Are both of them the same?

Comment: Not with any standard-compliant C code...

Comment: If it's the address-*bus*, `sizeof(pointer)` will not necessarily tell you that either.

Comment: On my 64-bit system, I routinely run code where the pointers are 32 bits. And "64 bits" is in any case a description of certain properties of the machine code for the platform - a fair number of those bits won't actually be present on the address bus because there's no point. When it's possible to install 17,179,869,184 GiB in a system current software will be able to exploit that but, for now, supporting that would be a completely pointless extra expense.

Comment: `dmidecode` on linux systems will read out tables built into PC BIOS's that include these details.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you can. One of the first computers I worked on was the Intel 8008 which has 
only one bus that was 8 bits wide; but the address space was 14 bits wide.